# Why are the same packages installed with older versions in certain linux distros?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian

So, I recently noticed that depending on which Linux machine I was running, valgrind would throw a solid 90k errors, for the exact same file/code that threw no errors using valgrind on a different machine. So, I looked into it, and it looks like while one is running valgrind-3.7.0, the other has valgrind-3.15.0. sudo apt update/upgrade didn't show anything, and reinstalling didn't make a difference. (For reference, I am using Raspbian on one and Ubuntu on the other)

Now the question: **Why are packages installed with different versions on different distributions? Would it be advisable to manually install the newer version on a distro that defaults to an older version? If so, what is the easiest way to do so?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes i have encountered such an issue.Some packages require older versions.The errors depend on the dependencies and your system configurations.

I guess to install an older version of what you want to install, do some research and try changing /etc/sources.list.

Comment: And if I would like to install a newer version? I'm assuming I'd have to make sure I also find a way to port over the dependencies.